# Multiple Variable Mysql Updates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, variables

i am currently coding an Interface for a Database i created. The Interface displays a table with X amount of rows. Based on the amount of rows i have a Form that has X amount of Dropdown Menus.

The Goal is to display all rows that have a certain status and then proceed to create one dropdown menu for each row. After the user selected the new status for each row and pressed a button, i want to update the rows column "status" to the new updated one.

Table Code:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultBestell))
    {
        $x++;
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["PrimKey"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["ID"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["ProduktID"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Menge"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Status"];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $test[$x] =$row["PrimKey"];
    @$safe += 1;
    }
    /////////////////////////
    echo count($test);
    echo $test[1];
    echo $test[2];
    echo $test[3];
    /////////////////////////
```

Dropdown Menu Code:

```
while($i != $safe)
{
    ?>
    <div class="w3-third">
    <label class="w3-text-teal">PrimKey <?php echo $test[$t];?></label>
    <select class="w3-select w3-border" name="<?php echo $t; ?>">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Status ausw&#228hlen</option>
    <option value="1">Unbearbeitet</option>
    <option value="2">Bearbeitet</option>
    <option value="3">Storniert</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <?php
    $i++;
    global $t;
    $t++;
    $z++;
}
```

SQL Update Code

```
while($i != $t)
    {
        $y = $test[$i];
        switch($_POST["$i"])
        {
            case 1:
                $sql = "UPDATE bestelldaten SET Status='Unbearbeitet' WHERE Primkey=$y";
                break;
            case 2:
                $sql = "UPDATE bestelldaten SET Status='Bearbeitet' WHERE Primkey=$y";
                break;
            case 3:
                $sql = "UPDATE bestelldaten SET Status='Storniert' WHERE Primkey=$y";
                break;
        }

        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
        {
            //Do Nothing
        }
        else
        {
            echo "ERROR" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
        $i++;
```

So i tried using $_SESSION but it gave me an ,,Skipping Numeric key 1 in unknown line 0" notice.

My attempt in the code above was to store the PrimKey value in an Array for every iteration of the while loop and then use the index to get the value. Couldn't figure out a way to make this work. Kept getting ,,Unknown offset" errors when i tried "WHERE = PrimKey=$test[$i]". I guess the values of my array get lost before i even reach the SQL Update part but i can't really figure out why or how to fix this.

Would appreciate some help, sorry if there is an obvious fix/answer for my problem. I'm fairly new to programming.

Comment: So u want to update the row when the user submits the form or when he changes the value of the dropdown menu?

Comment: When he submits the form. So that he can basically change the status of multiple rows in one form, press the submit button and then the rows get updated.

Comment: ok, in the form u need a hidden field with the primary key.
`<input type="hidden" name="PrimKey" value="<?=$row['PrimKey']?>">`
An then in the function u are processing the form values you gett the value with `$_POST['PrimKey']`

Comment: An input tag `name=` value can be used more than once. It can be duplicated. It doesn't have to be unique. You may wanna consider that. Just enclose each records' `input` tags in its own `<form>` . So if you submit the record's `form`, you only handle that one record when updating.